# How to push data into a chart.js data

Tags: javascript, mysql

i would like to pass the data from mysql database into my chart.js chart.

```
var myChartData = {
        labels: ["7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"],
        datasets: [{
                label: 'myLabel',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.8)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: []
            }]
};

$.get("myChart.php", function(data){
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
            myChartData.datasets[0].data.push(result[0],result[1],result[2],result[3],result[4],result[5],result[6],result[7],result[8],result[9],result[10],result[11],result[12],result[13]);
            myBarChart.update();
})
```

this is working but how can i push data with a for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `concat()` method:

```
myChartData.datasets[0].data = myChartData.datasets[0].data.concat(result);
```